# Pintar una tabla con php

Tags: php, mysql

El resultado de esta  consulta  la quiero convertir a una tabla, siendo que la consulta es un valo de un  mismo campo llamado nombre

```
  SELECT 
    id_departamento, departamento.nombre FROM `departamento` 
  WHERE  
    departamento.id_raiz= '1'
```

Arroga cada uno de los nombre de equipos que hay

```
id_Departamento     Nombre
             4      Domper/Desestibador
             5      Primera banda
             6      Primer mesa de seleccion
             7      Descarte de primer mesa
```

Etc.. son 42 nombres en total
Esa informcion la quiero mostrar en una tabla

y tengo este codigo

```
         <?php 
            include("dbconnect.php");
            $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_departamento, 
            departamento.nombre FROM `departamento` WHERE   
            departamento.id_raiz= '1'  ");
            $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->rowCount () > 0){

          echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
          while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
              for ($i=0; $i < 6 ; $i++) {
                echo "<tr>";

              for ($j=0; $j < 7 ; $j++) {
                echo "<td>".$rows['nombre']."</td>";
                  }
                echo "</tr>";
              }
            }
            echo "</table>";
          }

         ?>
```

Este codigo me manda esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber como le hago para que no me repita cada fila, pero que me mande un recuadro con toda la informacion asi como esta pero que no este repetida

Comment: es porque estas metiendo los resultados dentero de unos for que no se porque los usas alli

Comment: ¿La solución de @CarlosQuintero no te funcionó? Esa debería ser la respuesta correcta, a no ser que tus datos vengan mal en la consulta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas utilizando unos bucles for que no deberían de estar allí, por eso se están repitiendo no solos las filas sino los campos también, prueba de esta manera:

```
echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
          while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo    "<td>".$rows['nombre']."</td>";
                echo    "<td>".$rows['apellido']."</td>";
                echo    "<td>".$rows['cedula']."</td>";
                echo    "<td>".$rows['etc']."</td>";
                echo    "<td>".$rows['etc1']."</td>";
                echo    "<td>".$rows['etc2']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
           }
echo "</table>";
```

eso te va a imprimir una fila por cada registro de tu tabla

EDICION:

He agregado esto pues creo que lo que quieres es que se forme de manera automatica la tabla con sus filas y columnas necesarias de acuerdo a la cantidad de elementos extraidos.

indicas que son 42, en ese caso se´ria algo asi:

```
echo "<table border = '1'>";
echo "<tr>";
          $con=1;
          while($rows=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
                echo    "<td>".$rows['nombre']."</td>";
                if($con % 7==0){
                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                }
           $con++;
           }
echo "</tr>
</table>";
```

esto retornaría una tabla más o menos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sea lo que buscas. Saludos

Comment: si eso era justamente lo que buscaba, muchisimas gracias Carlos quintero

Comment: en ese caso marca la respuesta como correcta para cerrar el tema. Saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si pero no quiero que me mande la informacion de esta manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si no que me forme la tabla con esa infomacion, en si que me mande la informacion en recuadras no solo en una fila hacia abajo

Comment: he modificado mi respuesta con lo que crees es lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

al final mi codigo quedo de la sigueinte manera 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo has solucionado, está muy bien que añadas el código en la respuesta. Pero nunca lo hagas como una imagen, es mejor que copies y pegues el código, de tal manera que si alguna otra persona lo necesita pueda copiarlo en lugar de tener que estar mirando la imagen para teclearlo.